# How do I link to an image from a folder outside of my localhost

Tags: html, node.js

I am working on embedded website that will be served by a device running Linux. We are trying to maintain a system where editable items are in root/var/data/..  and static files are in root/opt/..

Right now my server.js is located at root/opt/webapp/server.js, i have an html file at root/opt/webapp/html/file.html

in the file.html i need to render images that are in the root/var/data folder, but my understanding of now this works is node considers localhost at root/opt/webapp(the location of server.js)  how do I  tag to a file that is outside of said local host but still within the file directory of the device?

I attempted an absolute path but the html just assumed that it should start the chain from localhost so

looks at http://localhost:8080/file:/C:/projects/root/var/data/fms/share/icons/avocado.png

Answer (score 0):

The `var` folder is two folders up from your `.html` file, so it sounds like you're looking for either:

- `../../var/data/fms/share/icons/avocado.png` (relative)
- `/root/var/data/fms/share/icons/avocado.png` (root-relative)

It depends on how you're linking to the file, but you may also be able to use the absolute path relative to `C:`:

- `file:///C:/projects/root/var/data/fms/share/icons/avocado.png`

Comment: absolute path comes back with: "Not allowed to load local resource:"   neither of the other two methods worked.